# How to disable drag option if option is not chosen from dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to disable drag option from "external-events-listing"  if option is "choose client" in drop down list ? and alert to select option from drop down list?

[This the complete code](http://jsbin.com/tusulux/edit?html,css,js,output)

Thanks in advance

```
<select id="client-list" onchange="changeImage(this)" style="width:150px; height:40px; margin-left:18px;margin-top:2px;">
<option value="Choose Client">---Choose Client---</option>
<option value="Client 1">Client 1</option>
<option value="Client 2">Client 2</option>
<option value="Client 3">Client 3</option>
<option value="Client 4">Client 4</option>
<option value="Client 5">Client 5</option>
</select>

    <div id='external-events'>
        <div id='external-events-listing'>
            <h4>Channel List</h4>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: and in calender at the top,I want to remove "all-day" option and display only time fields in calender

Comment: Only enable draggable on selected item ?

Comment: i mean i want to drag items only when i have selected some option other than choose client in drop down, or else it should be disabled(dragging items)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  // ...
  allDaySlot: false,
  // ...
});

$("#client-list").on("change", function() {
  // ...
  $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {
    if ($("#client-list").val() !== "Choose Client") {
      $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,     
        revertDuration: 0 
      });
    } else {
      $(this).draggable('disable');
    }
  });
  // ...
});

$('#client-list').trigger('change');
```

```
if (selectedValue !== "Choose Client") {
 $(this).draggable('enable');
} else {
 $(this).draggable('disable');
}
```

If selected is not 'Choose Client' then all events are draggable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* initialize the external events
  -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

  $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {


    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', {
      title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
      stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
      zIndex: 999,
      revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
      revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
    });

  });

  /* initialize the calendar
  -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    unselectAuto: false,
    selectable: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    selectHelper: false,
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    drop: function() {},
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.find(".fc-content").append("<span class='close' data-id='" + event._id + "'>x</span>");
    },
    eventResize: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
      console.log("event", event);
    },
  });
});

// remove event on click in calender
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {

  /* ------------------------------ */
  // debugger; // I commented out 
  /* ------------------------------ */

  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', id);
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$("#btnReset").click(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#client-list").on("change", function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    /* ------------------------------ */
    // location.reload(); // I commented out 
    /* ------------------------------ */

    // IF #client-list value is not 'Choose Client' then all are draggable. ELSE none are draggable.
    /* ------------------------------ */
    $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {
      if (selectedValue !== "Choose Client") {
        $(this).draggable('enable');
      } else {
        $(this).draggable('disable');
      }
    });
    /* ------------------------------ */


  });

  // Trigger change on load, to check the current #client-list value and 'enable' / 'disable' draggable to items.
  /* ------------------------------ */
  $('#client-list').trigger('change');
  /* ------------------------------ */

});
```

```css
button.remove {
  font-size: .85em;
  border: 1px solid #3a87ad;
  background-color: #3a87ad;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

calender-body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.fc-content span.close {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#wrap {
  width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#external-events {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: left;
}

#external-events h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

#external-events .fc-event {
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#external-events p {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #666;
}

#external-events p input {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#calendar {
  float: left;
  width: 1150px;
}

.mb-20 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  z-index: 32;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--scripts-->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<div id='wrap'>
  <img src="" alt="client logo" id='client-logo' height=80 width=80 style="float: left;margin-left:45px;">
  <div class="clients" style="float:left;clear:left;">
    <select id="client-list" onchange="/* changeImage(this) */" style="width:150px; height:40px; margin-left:18px;margin-top:2px;">
<option value="Choose Client">---Choose Client---</option>
<option value="Client 1">Client 1</option>
<option value="Client 2">Client 2</option>
<option value="Client 3">Client 3</option>
<option value="Client 4">Client 4</option>
<option value="Client 5">Client 5</option>
</select>

    <div id='external-events'>
      <div id='external-events-listing'>
        <h4>Channel List</h4>
        <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
        <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
        <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
        <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
        <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <span type="reset" id="btnReset" class="btn btn-default" style="margin
    top: 10px;">Reset Calender</span>
      <ul id="daysEvent"></ul>
      <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: but if i add if-else statement in the script its not working for me